# (Dis)prove for a matrix $A$ and for an unitary matrix $S$, where $D = S^{-1}AS$ a diagonal is which diagonalelements are imaginary that $A^{*} = - A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A \in M_{n,n}(\mathbb{C})$ a complex matrix and $ S \in U_{n}$ an unitary matrix with $D = S^{-1}AS$  a diagonalmatrix, which has only imaginary elements in it's diagonal. (the real part elements are $0$) applies that $A^{*} = - A$

My first thought was that $|det(S)|=1$ and unitary matrices are invertible with $U^{-1}=U^*$

The columns of $U$  form an orthonormal basis of $ \mathbb{C} $ with respect to the usual inner product. Which means that $U^*U=I$

The rows of $U$  form an orthonormal basis of $ \mathbb{C} $ with respect to the usual inner
product. Which means that $UU^*=I$

I got stuck at this point I'm even not sure that this is the right way to find the solution of the exercise. I would appreciate your helps a lot.

Comment: Please fix the title.

Comment: Use `\det` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about needing to use that $S^{-1}=S^*$. Since $D=S^*AS$, we can use this to write $A$ as $(S^*)^*DS^*$, and since $(B^*)^*=B$ for any matrix $B$, we get that $A=SDS^*$. Now we take the Hermitian transpose of both sides and get that $A^*=SD^*S^*$ using that $(BC)^*=C^*B^*$. This looks very similar to the equation for $A$. Once you are here, you need to find a relation for $D^*$ and should be done then. Hope this helps.

Comment: could you help me how to find $D*$ I'm still struggling with this step for a while. Thank you in advance

Comment: I think if you just do a $2\times 2$ example of $D$ and $D^*$ you’d see it.